# Convert 3d point to 2d screen coordinates in Maya Api

Tags: 3d, coordinates, maya

Working in Maya API (c++), I am looking for a way to convert a 3d coordinate into 2d screen position. Is there any easy way to do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably using the M3dView::worldToView() API
http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m3d_view_html

but because of the nature of the Maya API, make sure you got the world coordinates from the API before calling the API.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.